# A Stulano family

Tags: logical-deduction, language, family

Shortly after embarking on your trans-oceanic voyage, you meet an extended family who speak Stulano.* Although you don't share a language, they quickly "adopt" you as one of their own. You pass a couple of days playing with the kids and trying, through much trial and error, to communicate. By the end of the week, you can understand simple sentence structures in Stulano, but you're still trying to figure out how everyone is related.

The family consists of:

- Four men: Boba, Chinu, Ghoregi, and Lesle
- Three women: Hana, Nesuadu, and Olivia
- Four boys: Mateho, Pietru, Stusla, and Timio
- Four girls: Aliche, Dido, Ionie, and Vasti

The children range in age from around nine years old down to baby Pietru, who's not even crawling yet.

---

Dido, one of the older girls, takes a particular interest in explaining her family to you. "Mateho is my *dresca*," she tells you proudly, pointing to a boy around her age, "and Stusla"--a solemn little boy of perhaps eighteen months--"is my *slui*. Our *bena* and *pama* are there." She points to Boba and Olivia. "*Pama* is the *merila* of her family. I am the *merila* of Stusla, but not of Mateho.

"Timio and Vasti here are my *pasli*," she says, as a younger boy and girl chase each other around you. "Timio is the *dresca*. Their *bena* is my *spiezu* Ghoregi, who is *Pama*'s *slui*. *Rumispo* Hana and *Spiezu* Lesle are also *Pama*'s *slui*. *Spiezu* Ghoregi's *neti* is *Rumispo* Nesuadu, and *Rumispo* Hana's *cico* is *Spiezu* Chinu. *Spiezu* Lesle doesn't have a *neti*."

"Dido!" calls a girl around Dido's age, beckoning to her from across the deck.

"Call me *Stitra* Dido," Dido yells back. The other girl comes toward her, speaking in rapid-fire Stulano, and Dido replies with equal gusto. The good-natured argument lasts for half a minute and ends with both girls shoving each other and laughing.

"Ionie is Timio and Vasti's *merila*," says Dido, "but she's my *pasli*."

"Yes, *Stitra* Dido," Ionie says, rolling her eyes. "But I **am** the *stitra* of Stusla and Aliche and Pietru."

"So am I," Dido replies. "I'm the *stitra* of all of you!"

"Not of Mateho," Ionie retorts.

"No, but Mateho is your *musua*."

Wanting to prevent another argument, you ask Ionie, "Nesuadu is your *pama*, yes?"

She nods brightly.

"And Olivia is your *rumispo*?"

The girls burst into laughter. "No, no!" Ionie corrects you, "she's my *snama*. She's Aliche and Pietru's *rumispo*. My *rumispo* isn't here--this is my *bena*'s family."

"So Boba is your..."

"*Locrale*."

"Is Lesle your *locrale*?"

Ionie nods again. "My *bena* is his *dresca*."

"And *Rumispo* Hana is his *merila*," says Dido, "although she's *Spiezu* Ghoregi's *slui*."

---

From what you now know about this family, fill in the blanks in the following statements:

1. Ghoregi is Lesle's ____.
2. Boba is Olivia's ____.
3. Hana is Vasti's ____.
4. Lesle is Stusla's ____.
5. Chinu is Aliche's ____.
6. Pietru is Dido's ____.
7. Timio is Ionie's ____.
8. Aliche is Pietru's ____.

Bonus question: What was Dido and Ionie's argument about?

* Stulano is a [constructed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language) made by me, but for the purposes of this question you can treat it as if it were a natural language. However, you should not assume that it categorizes family relationships the same way as English does! You may assume that every child in this family has a father and mother who are monogamously married to each other, and that none of the children are married.

Comment: Ok, so I can't pull out the final answer, but here's my take so far: _spiezu_ and _locrale_ mean something like 'uncle', with _rumispo_ and _snama_ as 'aunt'. _Dresca_ is brother, without a doubt. There seems to be an important distinction between older/younger, with _slui_ only used for younger relations while _merila_ and _stitra_ are only for older. _neti_ and _cico_ might indicate marriage. Not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Some translations**

Immediate family

> bena = father
> pama = mother
> dresca = older brother
> merila = older sister
> slui = younger sibling
> neti = wife
> cico = husband

Extended family

> pasli = cousin
> stitra = older female cousin
> musua = older male cousin
> rumispo = aunt (mother's side)
> spiezu = uncle (mother's side)
> snama = aunt (father's side)
> locrale = uncle (father's side)

Family tree

> [image: Family tree] 
> Siblings are arranged from oldest > youngest

### Answers

> Ghoregi is Lesle's **dresca**.
> Boba is Olivia's **cico**.
> Hana is Vasti's **snama**.
> Lesle is Stusla's **spiezu**.
> Chinu is Aliche's **bena**.
> Pietru is Dido's **pasli**.
> Timio is Ionie's **slui**.
> Aliche is Pietru's **merila**.

Bonus:

> Dido and Ionie were arguing over who is older.

Comment: But Dido refers to Chinu as Spiezu and Nesuadu as Rumispo, which aren't reflected in your family tree.. are there multiple incestuous relationships going on here?

Comment: @doog oh you're right, I changed some translations from my original wording but I forgot to keep that in consideration. I'll change them back now